# How to configure a Cisco Catalyst 2960 to synchronize with an NTP server

Tags: cisco, ntp, time, timezone, cisco-catalyst

I would like to synchronize a Cisco Catalyst 2960 series switch with a publicly available NTP server such as time.apple.com. I have reviewed the knowledge base article here: 
[Catalyst 2960 Configuration Guide](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2960/software/release/12-2_55_se/configuration/guide/scg_2960/swadmin.html#wp1020815) but am not entirely sure which parts of the "Configuring NTP" subsection are relevant to my configuration.

- How can I configure the Catalyst Switch to use an NTP server as its time source?
- How can I confirm that the time is synchronized successfully with the NTP source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example config:

```
shipping-2960# show run | i ntp

ntp server 207.182.243.123
ntp server 69.65.40.29 prefer
ntp server 208.53.158.34
```

To check status:

```
shipping-2960# show ntp status

Clock is synchronized, stratum 3, reference is 207.182.243.123
nominal freq is 190.7348 Hz, actual freq is 190.7286 Hz, precision is 2**18
reference time is D75F39BB.6F04B482 (21:08:59.433 CDT Wed Jul 2 2014)
clock offset is -6.8457 msec, root delay is 62.21 msec
root dispersion is 63.61 msec, peer dispersion is 14.11 msec
```

Comment: Thanks @ewwhite quick follow up. What command(s) do you use to set the NTP server?

Comment: @dean I strongly suspect that he uses the commands that he provided as examples above.

Comment: The switch is not functioning as the NTP server but as a NTP client. He's asking about the NTP server.

Comment: Also `show ntp association` is a brief output of each NTP server, it's statistics and master/secondary selection.